# Max allowed measurements error

Tags: current-measurement, measurement, voltage-measurement, error

Since it's not possible to know with 100% accuracy about what's going on in a circuit and its components, and I have to trust my multimeter on measurements, what's the usual approach to managing errors?

Let's say I want to build a simple device or a circuit, and I know what materials I'll be using, how do I find out in what range my measurements for things like resistance or current can be off, to reduce the chance of damaging components?

Comment: Even a cheap meter is good to 1% or better, and I can't think of any cases where a 1% difference will DAMAGE a circuit.

Comment: You can't use a DMM to measure the SOA (safe operating area of V(t)*I(t)=Pd ) of switching a reactive load. But your finger will tell you if it is too hot.

Comment: Part of the fun of electronics is the high value of mental modeling, once a bucket of physical phenomena are in your grasp. Thus .... learn more physics ... and  your world alters also.

Answer (score 0):

The only component I can think of which might be damaged by an error in the order of 1% is the charge voltage for lithium based cells. Even with those, that sort of error will change the lifetime number of cycles, rather than cause prompt damage.

You can expect even the cheapest meter to have been checked in the factory to its specification.

If you have several meters, or can borrow one from a friend or school, then you can compare them.

I bought a voltage reference IC, specified to be accurate to 0.1%, for around £2, to check my multimeters. Actually, ever paranoid, I bought two, so that I could compare them as well.

Comment: I tried my multimeter on a drill battery (18V) and it's displayed value was jumping rapidly between 16V and 22V, does that mean my multimeter is bad or I wasn't accounting for something?

Comment: Nvm I tested again and it's showing 19.5V steadily. That seems like a large error, no? Unless it's supposed to add 1.5V on top of the real value.

Comment: @Greg A battery is not an accurate voltage reference, the voltage is at best a nominal value, but it should be steady. An 18v NiMH battery could be anywhere between 20v and 0v (ideally above 15v) depending on the  state of charge. A 5 cell LiPo could be anywhere between 21v and 15v (ideally above 16.5v) depending on SoC.